# Add company name to WooCommerce "New Order" email

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

How do I add the company name as the subject / title for the WooCommerce order e-mail? So when a customer places an order, we'd like to receive an email saying "New B2B order from (COMPANY NAME). We get the company name in the WooCommerce checkout and I tried adding it using {company_name} but without luck.

Answer (score 1):

If you used the `woocommerce_form_field()` function to create the field in the checkout, you can access it via key and use the filter `woocommerce_email_order_meta_keys` to place it inside of the emails. The value of your field has to be part of the order meta data.

Create a custom plugin or place the code inside of the function.php of your theme:

```
function yourfield_display_in_email( $keys ) {
     $keys['your-label'] = '_your_key';
     return $keys;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_order_meta_keys', 'yourfield_display_in_email' );
```

Don't fortget to put the `_` before the key name, like in `_your_key`.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help.  How do I find the value of the field?

Comment: I think the key of the company name is `billing_company`. It is the name which is added to the billing information (order meta).